PlayFramework 3.0 + Java + scala3 で、ErrorHandler#onDevServerErrorから「Apply this script now!」画面に遷移したい
この単純なコードで表している事を実現したいです。よろしくお願いします。
public class ErrorHandler extends DefaultHttpErrorHandler {

    protected CompletionStage<Result> onDevServerError​(Http.RequestHeader request,
            play.api.UsefulException exception) {
        logger.debug(" request=" + request + " exception=" + exception);
        if (0 == exception.getMessage().indexOf("Database 'default' needs evolution!")) {

            // ここで「Apply this script now!」画面に遷移したい

            // return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
            //      Results.internalServerError("[DEV] A server error occurred: " +         
            //      exception.getMessage()));
        }
        BaseForm baseform = new BaseForm();
        Form<BaseForm> bf = formFactory.form(BaseForm.class).fill(baseform);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
                Results.notFound(irregularError.render(bf, (Request) request)));
    }

}


